# uinavigationController leftButton frame issue ios6 and ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7

issue is in ios7,ios6 is fine and i m working on xcode 5

[image]

```
 UIImage *backButtonBackgroundImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,backButtonBackgroundImg.size.width, backButtonBackgroundImg.size.height);
[backButton setImage:backButtonBackgroundImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
backButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont smallSystemFontSize]];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
```

Comment: And where is the question?

Comment: @rckoenes see both menu icon. the position are misalignment

Comment: you can use UIBarButtonItem it could easily solved. why use for UIButton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've faced similar problem. I am not sure why this happens, but I've been able to fix this problem. Try this code below:

```
#define IS_IOS_7_OR_LATER() ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
if (IS_IOS_7_OR_LATER())
{
   backButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -30, 0, 0);
}
```

This should help you. Cheers!

Comment: PLease do not detect iOS version with the `systemVersion` but with the foundentaion version. `if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
   // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
} else {
   // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
}`

Comment: thank you, but what is the problem with using system version?

Comment: check my answer for the reason why its happen

Comment: thanku so much Shabib it really works :)

Comment: @Shabib I wrote an [article](http://triplesoftware.nl/2014/02/checking-device-or-system-version/) in my you should never check the systemer version. Also apple suggest that you use the foundation check instate of the system version check.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this

You can specify buttons and views to display on the left side of the toolbar using the leftBarButtonItems property but the navigation controller displays **those buttons only if there is space available**.

[apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html)

so you can use UIBarButtonItem it could easily solved. why use for UIButton

your button frame should be change

```
 NSLog(@"button frame %@",NSStringFromCGRect(backButton.frame));
```

In iOS 6

button frame {{5, 43}, {28, 18}}

In iOS 7

button frame {{16, 43}, {28, 18}}